# boto3 show next available device name on instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

Using boto3, what is the best way to show the next available device name on an instance resource?

Example utilized instance block devices:

```
/dev/sda
/dev/sdb
/dev/sdd
/dev/sde
/dev/sdf
```

`/dev/sdc` is open so i'd like the attach my volume there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def get_free_device_name(instance):
    all_device_names = ["/dev/xvd%s" % (x) for x in ascii_lowercase]
    device_list = instance.block_device_mappings
    used_device_names = set()
    for device in device_list:
        used_device_names.add(device['DeviceName'])
    return list(set(all_device_names) - used_device_names).pop()
```

Comment: In trying to use this code, I found the set of brackets around this line cause an error: `used_device_names.add([device['DeviceName']])`

This works:

`used_device_names.add(device['DeviceName'])`